# How to detect that my library is running under .Net Core 3 Desktop Package

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms, .net-core

Here is how I can detect it now (this approach is based on internal changes in Desktop Package classes):

```
public static class FrameworkVersions {
    static readonly bool f_nativeMatrix_Exists;
    static FrameworkVersions() {
        f_nativeMatrix_Exists= typeof(System.Drawing.Drawing2DMatrix)
            .GetField("nativeMatrix", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic) != null;
    }
    public static bool IsNetCore3DesktopPackage {
        get{ return !f_nativeMatrix_Exists; }
    }
}
```

Is the best way exists? Please share your experience.

Answer (score 5):

You can rely on [`RuntimeInformation.FrameworkDescription`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.runtimeinformation?view=netframework-4.7.2) like what is used in .NET Core [tests](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/v2.1-preview1/src/CoreFx.Private.TestUtilities/src/System/PlatformDetection.cs#L25):

```
//using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
bool IsFullFramework = RuntimeInformation.FrameworkDescription.StartsWith(".NET Framework",
    StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
bool IsNetNative = RuntimeInformation.FrameworkDescription.StartsWith(".NET Native",
    StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
bool IsNetCore = RuntimeInformation.FrameworkDescription.StartsWith(".NET Core", 
    StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

You can also detect the running framework version by finding [`TargetFrameworkAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.versioning.targetframeworkattribute?view=netframework-4.7.2) of the assembly (like this [blog post](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2018/Apr/12/Getting-the-NET-Core-Runtime-Version-in-a-Running-Application) by Rick Strahl):

```
//using System.Reflection;
//using System.Runtime.Versioning;
var framework = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()?
    .GetCustomAttribute<TargetFrameworkAttribute>()?
    .FrameworkName;
MessageBox.Show(framework);
```

Comment: Thanks, but how can I avoid "magical strings matching" and/or versions parsing in this case? what if the ".NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1" will be changed to 2.1.1, 2.3-alpha and etc...

Comment: I added a piece of code which is currently used by .NET Core team in tests. Take a look at [PlatformDetection](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/v2.1-preview1/src/CoreFx.Private.TestUtilities/src/System/PlatformDetection.cs#L25).

Comment: Thanks for the great addition! However, this way still has limitations because there is no `RuntimeInformation` type in .net framework under v4.7.1 (we are still on v4.5.2 and should provide the desktop controls with a single code-base which works fine under the .net framework and at the same time under the .net core 3). Thus we are still using the `nativeMatrix` way.

Comment: For future readers: Regarding to the documentations, the [`RuntimeInfromrtaion`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.runtimeinformation) is available for the following .NET versions: **.NET Core**:
2.2, 2.1, 2.0, 1.1, 1.0 
**.NET Framework**: 4.8, 4.7.2, 4.7.1 **.NET Standard**: 2.0, 1.6, 1.4, 1.3, 1.2, 1.1